# React Native Synchronize parent and child state

Tags: react-native

Say i have a Parent component and a Child component which both have states with a value in common 'item'.
How do i synchronise the 'item' value in the Parent and Child states ?
To be more concrete, the parent could be a page of the app and the child could be a personnalized input. When i write in the input i want the page state to be updated and when the page state is updated by an external factor (say by a notification) i want the input to be updated.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      item: 1,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        item = this.state.item
      />
    )
  }

  // I want any function of this type to automatically update
  // child state (and redraw child) without having to manually resynchronise
  modifyItem() {
    this.setState({ item: neValue })
  }

}

export default class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      item: this.props.item,
    }
  }

  // I want any function of this type to automatically update
  // parent state without having to manually resynchronise
  modifyItem() {
    this.setState({ item: neValue })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      item: 1,
    }
  }
  onItemChange(item) {
    this.setState({ item });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        item = this.state.item
        onItemChange={this.onItemChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }

  // I want any function of this type to automatically update
  // child state (and redraw child) without having to manually resynchronise
  modifyItem() {
    this.setState({ item: neValue })
  }

}

export default class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      item: this.props.item,
    }
  }

  // I want any function of this type to automatically update
  // parent state without having to manually resynchronise
  modifyItem() {
    this.setState({ item: newValue })
    if (this.props.onItemChange) {
       this.props.onItemChange(newValue);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's a manual trick there is no automated synchronisation here. I don't know if what i'm looking for i doable but that is not the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Try using Redux or Mobx for centralised store and dispatch event with new value. That will work